# VSTO Addin Creates 2 items in Add/Remove programs

Tags: ms-office, vsto, installshield, installshield-le

I have created a vsto addin in VS2012. I have added an installation project to the solution using Installsheild LE. After installing the exe that I get, I get the expected item added to my add/remove programs. However when I open Word, I get prompted with a Microsoft Office Customization Installer prompt which says the publisher is unknown. I click OK to this and it adds my addin as expected, which all works fine but I also get a second item appear in my add/remove programs.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the second item in add/remove programs and offer any advice about what I should do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "|vstolocal"  to the addin registry value that points to your addin file.  This tells ClickOnce to run it directly and not install it per-user.

You also want to digitally sign the addin using a certificate issued by someone in the users trusted root.  This could be VeriSign or others.  If you create your own certificate you have to use custom actions to install the root certificate in the certificate store and to register the publisher cert as a trusted publisher.

I've created about a dozen of these installers over the last 8 years and it's tricky at first but gets easier over time.  Several of my customers are using InstallShield LE to get the prereqs installed but then I factor all the components out into a WiX merge module where I can use things like the Util extension to install certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use ClickOnce and MSI installers to deploy the add-in. You need to remove any of them. Both kind of installers are described in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is that your dev machine and got Visual Studio in it? I have seen this happened with Windows 7 during development the addin is added in to add/remove programs. This has gone later when I updated my Windows 7 machine. Some updates from Microsoft has removed this later.